# Conditioned occurrence calculation in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Considering the data frame below (2 columns : id and val) , I am trying to find a fast way to calculate the occurrence of an element "boo"  from column *val* in  unique events.
The events are represented in column *id* . The unique events are : a,b,c,d

```
id<-c("a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","d")
val<-c("boo","sd","ssd","df","boo","ksdj","boo","sdjhf","df","boo")
x<-data.frame(id,val)
```

Thus the result here should be 4 as "boo" appears in all events : a,b,c,d .

```
Count("boo") =4
```

Example2

```
id<-c("a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","d")
val<-c("boo","sd","ssd","df","boo","ksdj","boo","sdjhf","boo","sgfsc")
x<-data.frame(id,val)

Count("boo") =3
```

I need to do this with packages from R base only.

Thank you.

Comment: Also I need to solve this with functions from R-base ( poor R integration )

Comment: Can you use the `plyr` package?  If not, then I will delete my answer, and you can go with @User7598 's response.

Comment: Regarding your specific requirements, I think you shouldn't use an example where all rows are unique already

Comment: I listed below;  I suggest you keep the answer though for others

Comment: What if you have `boo` twice within a certain group? In other words, would just `sum(with(x, tapply(val, id, function(x) any(x == "boo"))))` work for you?

Comment: @David- yes I am interested in the unique counts of boo in the unique events ; I think that works best for me;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unique counts of `boo` using base R, one could do

```
sum(with(x, tapply(val, id, function(x) any(x == "boo"))))
## [1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> result <- ddply(x,~val,nrow)
> result <- result[result$V1==4, ]
> result
  val V1
1 boo  4
```

The data frame `result` will have the number of rows for each `val`, and we can subset it further to select only `val` which have a value of 4 (indicating that it occurred for every `id`).

Here is a slightly less elegant solution using only base-R functions (your requirement):

```
> result <- sapply(split(x, x$val), function(x) nrow(x))
> result
  boo    df  ksdj    sd sdjhf sgfsc   ssd
    4     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

If you want to find `val` which occur with a certain frequency, you can subset `result` like this:

```
> result[result >= 4]
boo
  4
```

Comment: Neat! unfortunately I cant use the plyr package  (or other packages ) as I am dealing with a poor R integration; everything needs to be done with R base; I

Comment: @agatha just make a table and count the `TRUE`s `sum(with(x, table(id, val == 'boo'))[, 'TRUE'])` gives me `[1] 4`

Comment: That would work, but it would be nice to get a report showing all the `val` which occur for every `id` in one command.

Comment: what? so then don't subset the table by `[, 'TRUE']` ? all OP wanted was the count

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1. subset unique rows
unique <- unique(x)

# 2. count unique rows with val == boo
sum(unique$val == "boo")
```